# «Redeem life» meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I’ve come across a song with such lyrics:

> Will you redeem my life again?

I’m not sure how to understand this phrase… My native language is Russian and regarding redemption we have a phrase “redeem sins”. But “redeem life” doesn’t really make much sense to me - especially given that it’s  someone else who should redeem his life (according to this lyrics). So I’m a bit confused here…

Comment: It's poetic -- means whatever the author thinks it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem) has various relevant meanings of redeem: "3: to change for the better: REFORM", "5 c: to make good: FULFILL", "6 b(1): to offset the bad effect of (2): to make worthwhile". The exact meaning of the song can't be judged just from 6 words, but it most likely means "will you make my life better?" or "will you make my life worth living again?" with the connotation that his life is currently worthless or bad.

Comment: Wow, this actually makes a lot of sense when you know the plot, to which this song is a soundtrack (I just didn’t want to pollute the question with too much details). Thanks!